# How to edit the loop php code to add external website address?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, echo

I apologize in advance for the primitive question, I'm not a knitter. 
I need to do to show button Order Now with external link to the website (website's address stored on the same place where is the address or phone number)  instead of Show Map. 
Now is:
[Now is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs370.png)

How do I need to overwrite the template's code to:

[Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXWuw.png)

Here is template's code:

```
 <?php
    if( ( !empty( $menu_check ) && is_array( $menu_check ) ) || ( !empty( $phone )  ) || ( !empty( $gAddress )  ) ):
        ?>
        <div class="lp-new-grid-bottom-button">
            <ul class="clearfix">

                <?php
                if( $is_phone == 'ok' ):
                ?>
                    <li class="show-number-wrap" style="<?php //if( $is_menu == '' ){ echo 'width:100%;'; } ?>">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="show-number"><?php esc_html_e('call','listingpro'); ?></span><a href="tel:<?php echo $phone; ?>" class="grind-number"><?php echo $phone; ?></a></p>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                if( $is_gAddress == 'ok' ):
                    ?>
                    <li style="<?php //if( $is_phone == '' ){ echo 'width:50%;'; } ?>">
                        <a href="" data-lid="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" data-lat="<?php echo $lp_lat; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $lp_lng; ?>" class="show-loop-map-popup"><i class="fa fa-map-pin" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Show Map','listingpro'); ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                if( $is_menu == 'ok' ):
                    ?>
                    <li style="<?php //if( $is_phone == '' ){ echo 'width:50%;'; } ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_the_ID() ); ?>/#lp-listing-menuu-wrap"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php esc_html_e('View Menu','listingpro'); ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sorry to say but your question is more of a request than a question and it's a rather vague one so even if someone wanted to help you out, there's little to go with.

Comment: Like "$is_phone" and "$phone" variables. the theme that you are using must have generated some kind of vaiable for the external link that you have stored. You need to use those variables to check if external website is added and then print its value. If can exhibit how you have added the external website link, then probably somebody can help further.